# How do I change the "login" label in My Account page to "Registered Customer"

Tags: php, woocommerce-offtopic

[image]

I manage to change the "register" label to "account registeration" with the code below:

******add_filter( 'gettext', 'ak_translate_woocommerce_strings', 999 );***
function ak_translate_woocommerce_strings( $translated ) {
if (is_account_page()) {
$translated = str_ireplace( 'Register', 'Account Registeration', $translated );
}
return $translated;
}***

And now I would like to change to "login" label to "Registered Customers". Can someone help?

I tried the same code changing the text only and i got a word press error. Below is the code i tried:

add_filter( 'gettext', 'ak_translate_woocommerce_strings', 999 );

***function ak_translate_woocommerce_strings( $translated ) {
if (is_account_page()) {
$translated = str_ireplace( 'Login', 'Registered Customers', $translated );
}
return $translated;
}***

And i got an error message:
[image]

Comment: You should be able to do it the same way. Does that not work?

Comment: I did but i got an error message when i go to my website.